# Wordpress: On specific url the admin toolbar shows up (Even when not logged in)

Tags: wordpress, toolbar

I'm running into a Major trouble.

Today I found out that when visiting a specific URL on my website, the admin toolbar shows up. Also for people who are not logged in. It appears that the visitor is logged in, but that's not true. All the links in the toolbar go to a 404 page. However, important information is being shown, like how many plugins need an update and even my login name.

Is anyone familiar with this?

Since it is a corporate website, I need a fix as soon as possible.
(due to security reasons I won't post the exact url in public)

Hopefully anyone can help me.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Try to add either of these code in functions.php of your theme,

Code 1:

```
<?php

add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

?>
```

Code 2:

```
function hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){

  remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );
```

Comment: Both codes don't work. And for the record, I want the admin toolbar when I am logged in as admin. It's just a weird bug that it appears on a specific url to visitors. I need this fixed.

Comment: Then try this,  function hide_admin_bar_from_front_end(){
  if (is_blog_admin()) {
    return true;
  }
  remove_action( 'wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb' );
  return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'hide_admin_bar_from_front_end' );